# How to keep my samples time constant wrt the system time in js?

Tags: javascript, date, amcharts

***Problem description***
There is a machine (let's say **Client**) executes some stats collection on a machine (let's call it **System Under Test(SUT)**). 
Stats are collected on the SUT and hence the milliseconds are from one timezone and the Client has different timezone.

These stats when plotted on the charts using AMCharts look like this.
[image: Look at it]

I plot a graph using AMCharts. The charts need samples and those are in milliseconds. The graph will plot and parse the dates and parsing involves passing the millis to the Date constructor.

When this happens everything works well until i go ahead and change my system's time. The samples also change on refresh since it uses

```
new Date(samples[ith-sample]);
```

How do i manage to keep my sample time constant irrespective of the system's time.

**Vocabulary**

**offset :** is the time difference i have to maintain between the machine where samples were collected and the machine who triggered the collection.
In the picture , the time difference is 3hours 30 minutes 1 second

***What have i tried yet ?***

```
var curDate = new Date();
var targetDate = new Date(curDate.getTime() - offset *1000); 
sampleData[0] = targetDate;
```

Comment: Well first thing would be to get the timezone and then subtract the offset accordingly.

Comment: I did but the since i get the targetDate using the Date constructor so the returned date always deviates from the accepted time difference (in this case its 3hrs:30mins:1sec)

Comment: Do you have control over the code collecting the samples?

Comment: @HugoSilva yes i do , the samples are being collected in a csv file.

Comment: I think changing all time ( source and targe) to GMT or to a specific timezone should solve the issue. What I think you should try is changing the output of new Date(sample[ith-sample]) to GMT as well as saving sampleData[0]  = ConvertToGMT(targetDate);

Answer (score 1):

When you start collecting the samples you can save the time, then you would subtract that number from every sample, saving only the time distance from the beginning. That way you are only comparing distances, regardless of timezone or even actual time. For example:

```
var samplingStartTime = Date.now();
function collectSample(){
    return Date.now() - samplingStartTime;
}
```

Then your chart is going to be a linear time scale starting at zero.

If you still want to use actual dates on your chart you can set an initial date at any point in time, then use that date + each sample value for your time axis.

Comment: I was thinking about your second approach (with actual dates). If i do what you said , then during sampling i have to store the starting date timestamp and return it to front end(where i plot the graph). Once i have the starting time, ill just keep adding each sample that would give me the desired dates irrespective of the System's time .

Is that what you implied?

Comment: I am getting confused about what is the front end, Client, SUT, and what role each machine you describe is playing. It is hard to undesrtand looking from outside. But the concept is that once you have your samples as time distance (and not dates), you can plot that consistently from any starting point you want. If you your starting point is the date when you started sampling on the Client, then yes, you should retrieve and use that date...